# Best way to Load 25 gigs text file to Mysql (python script or LOAD DATA )?

Tags: python, mysql, performance

I am trying to load a file that around 25 gigabyte to MYsql i was going to write a script but saw a stackoverflow thread of load data command so trying

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_path\\test.txt' INTO TABLE my_table
fields terminated by ":";
```

the result was seeming to be ok but the mysql workbench connection seems to drop after a while maybe because of the file size of course. so what can i do, and is python script be more efficient in this case and more importantly more reliable since i cant withstand of any error of course occurring in the middle of this long process.

Comment: Use the commandline tool `mysql`, not Workbench, and set the timeouts suitably high.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the data in chunks using python script with multiple thread as per your system configuration.